# repeat the string sequence until it reaches a certain length in java

Tags: java, string

I have two strings `plainText` and `key`. Now, if the `plainText.length > key.length` then i have to repeat the key until its the same length as that of `plainText`. here's an example:

```
plainText = "helloworld"
key="foobar"
```

hence the key should be increased to "foobarfoob".

One solution is to repeat the entire word and then remove the last characters until it reaches the same length as of plainText like "foobarfoobar" and then remove the characters "ar" .

Is there any better (or rather and Elegant) way to do this in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution seems reasonable, other than the way you remove the last characters - don't do it one at a time, just use substring or `StringBuilder.setLength()`:

```
// Make sure we never have to expand...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(plainText.length() + key.length() - 1);
while (builder.length() < plainText.length()) {
    builder.append(key);
}
builder.setLength(plainText.length());
String result = builder.toString();
```

Or just change the append call to only get to the right size:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(plainText.length());
while (builder.length() < plainText.length()) {
    builder.append(key.substring(0, Math.min(key.length(),
                                        builder.length() - plainText.length()));
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Personally I prefer the first - it's simpler.

Comment: The first one is much better and simpler! thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal (admittedly not very self-explanatory, but compact and efficient) - it repeats key as many times as necessary + 1 and uses substring to remove the extra characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String plainText = "helloworld";
    String key = "foobar";
    int repeat = plainText.length() / key.length();
    int remainder = plainText.length() % key.length();

    String result = new String(new char[repeat + 1]).replaceAll(".", key).substring(0, key.length() * repeat + remainder);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Ummm ... I beg to differ.  This is neither more compact or more efficient than using `StringBuilder` and a loop.  And certainly, it is a LOT more complicated.

Comment: @StephenC After thinking about - I think I agree! It's more useful for a code golf than for production code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over key and in every step count the steps(which should be some time equal to plaintext => stop) and add those chars of every step to key. this is done in one loop